# Snowflake-sqlalchemy can't inspect column comments

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

## Problem

When inspecting columns on Snowflake tables with SQLAlchemy, the column comments are not visible.

## [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

### Requirements

```sh
pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy
```

**Test**

```python
import sqlalchemy

# set up the connection
snowflake_conn = '<your-connection-string-here>'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(snowflake_conn)

# create a table for testing, add a column comment
engine.execute('create table public.test ("col1" text);')
engine.execute("""alter table public.test alter "col1" comment 'this is my comment'""")

# check if comment is successfully stored in the information schema
engine.execute("select comment from information_schema.columns where table_name='TEST'").fetchall()
# Output: [('this is my comment',)]


# now let's try to inspect the table
inspector = sqlalchemy.inspect(engine)
inspector.get_columns('TEST', schema='PUBLIC')
```

**Actual result**

```
[{'name': 'col1',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=16777216),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False,
  'primary_key': False}]
```

**Expected result**

```
[{'name': 'col1',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=16777216),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'comment': 'this is my comment',  # <-- this is added
  'autoincrement': False,
  'primary_key': False}]
```

## Question

Am I doing something wrong to inspect for column comments, or is this simply a bug in snowflake-sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your (well prepared) code with `snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.1.18`, and the comment is now returned as expected.

```
{
   'name' : 'col1',
   'primary_key' : False,
   'default' : 'None',
   'type' : VARCHAR(length=16777216),
   'nullable' : True,
   'autoincrement' : False,
   'comment' : 'this is my comment'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for testing, seems that it's been fixed in the latest release. Cool

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting your finding!

This seems to be a problem in `snowflake-sqlalchemy`, we have started investigation of the problem, keep an eye on here for updates: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/90

Comment: Thanks Mark, will keep an eye on the ticket.